# jquery-plugin datepicker does not work when cloned

Tags: jquery

I have a following codes (markup and javascript) in which each block of 2 text boxes are cloned. Each block contains 2 text box; one with normal text box; the other is text box (id of "textboxDueDate") with datepicker plug in associating with. Only the first/original works with popup calendar when user clicks inside it. However, cloned "textboxDueDate" text boxes does not have popup calendar showed when they are clicked inside. What are wrong with my codes?

```
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="buttonAddBookTrack" value="Add Another Book Track" />
</div>

        <div id="divTemplate">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Book</legend>
            <div>
                <label>Book ISBN: </label>
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
             <div>
                <label>Due Date: </label>
                <input type="text" id="textboxDueDate" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
</div>

        <div id="divOtherBooks"></div>


<!-- java script ---->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _idCount = 1;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[id^=textboxDueDate]').datepicker(); 

        $('#buttonAddBookTrack').click(function () {
            var appendedDiv = $('<div>').appendTo('#divOtherBooks').data('divClonedTemplate', '_' + _idCount);
            $('#divTemplate').children().clone().appendTo(appendedDiv);

            $('input[id^=textboxDueDate]').not('.hasDatePicker').datepicker();  

            _idCount++;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you need to `TICK` the solution which works for you, see a 'Tick' mark appear besides each answer

Answer (score 1):

Make two things sure :

a) remove the  'hasDatePicker' class after cloning the text field

b) Add a unique ID to text field

check the [working code](http://jsfiddle.net/9fp66/)

```
var _idCount = 1;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[id^=textboxDueDate]').datepicker();

        $('#buttonAddBookTrack').click(function () {
            var appendedDiv = $('<div>')
                .appendTo('#divOtherBooks')
                .data('divClonedTemplate', '_' + _idCount);

            var nodeO=$('#divTemplate').children().clone()
                $(nodeO).find('input[id^=textboxDueDate]')
                 .attr('id','textboxDueDate_'+_idCount)
                 .removeClass('hasDatepicker')
                 .datepicker()

            $(nodeO).appendTo(appendedDiv)


            _idCount++;
        });
    });
```

You and trim the code , I have added extra lines of code just for clarity

**Edit : Why `removeClass('hasDatepicker')` ?**

The datepicker() actually checks the class to determine if datepicker object is not defined for the given textbox . In your case , when you clone you get that class as `garbage` which prevents 
 datepicker() from being initiated

Comment: I have a question over here. Why do we need the code line such as  .removeClass('hasDatepicker')
?

Comment: check my edits for you query regarding `.removeClass('hasDatepicker')`

Answer (score 0):

Using a deep [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/):

```
$('#divTemplate').children().clone(true, true).appendTo(appendedDiv);
```

has the problem of keep the events binded to the original element.

So, bind the event after cloning instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#buttonAddBookTrack').click(function () {
    var $appendedDiv = $("#divTemplate")
      .clone()
      // Remove divTemplate's id
      .removeAttr("id")
      .appendTo('#divOtherBooks')
      .data('divClonedTemplate', '_' + _idCount);
    $("#textboxDueDate", $appendedDiv)
      // Remove datepicker plugin data
      .removeData("datepicker")
      // Remove element's parent id
      // Note: DatePicker will automatically generate an id
      .removeAttr("id")
      .datepicker();
    _idCount++;
  });
});
```

You could save the steps for removing DatePicker data from cloned element if you assure your `divTemplate` element won't be used anywhere.

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of code line such as  $('#textboxDueDate', appendedDiv).datepicker();  ?

Comment: The problem I see with this solution is if I change the date in some non-first Due Date textbox, the data will affect the 1st Due Date text box instead the worked-on text box.

Comment: @user1219702, I updated the answer addressing this and improved the working one.

Comment: `$('#textboxDueDate', $appendedDiv)` uses `$appendedDiv` as the root node for filtering.